# list comprehension return a single value instead of a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a dataframe that consists of tuples shaped like this:

```
Prices
(0, 30.00)
(0, 20.00)
(0, 33.00)
(-12.00, 0)
(-13.00, 0)
(0,0)
```

I need to grab the non-zero values from each of the tuples if it exists and replace the tuple as a float in the column.

I used list comprehension, but it returns the value as a list instead of a float. Is there a better way to accomplish this? or an easy way to convert the list (of length 1) to a float?

I am using python pandas

```
df['Prices'] = [[next((val for val in ls if val != 0), 0)] for ls in df['Prices'].values]
```

Comment: you can directly extract the non-zero value (or 0 if both are zero) using the `next` function within the list comprehension.

Comment: `[next((val for val in ls if val != 0), 0)] ` you are unnecessarily wrapping that in a list. If you don't want a list, don't create the unnecessary list, so just `next(...)` instead of `[next(...)]`

Comment: `np.c_[df['Prices'].to_list()].sum(1)` in case you have exactly the same structure for all the prices and only one non-zero value

Comment: Is always one of the values in each tuple guaranteed to be zero?

Comment: @vakvakvak Yes there will always be a zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list comprehension creates an unnecessary inner list because that is what you wrote, you are unnecessarily wrapping that in a list. If you don't want a list, don't create the unnecessary list, so just `next(...)` instead of `[next(...)]`:

```
[next((val for val in ls if val != 0), 0)]
```

Should just be:

```
next((val for val in ls if val != 0), 0)
```

So:

```
df['Prices'] = [next((val for val in ls if val != 0), 0) for ls in df['Prices'].values]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Prices'] = [float(next((val for val in tpl if val != 0), 0)) for tpl in df['Prices']]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
Prices
0    30.0
1    20.0
2    33.0
3   -12.0
4   -13.0
5     0.0
```

Here just changed one thing instead of changing to list the element converted it to float

Answer (score 0):

If at least one value of the tuple is guaranteed to be zero, you can simply do

```
df['Prices'] = [ float(tpl[0] | tpl[1]) for tpl in df['Prices']]
```